# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change my app from stateful widgets to provider. I put a function in the provider class and for some reason, it keeps giving me this error when I try calling the function. Below is the code for it. Thanks.

```
`onTap: Provider.of<Infomation>(context).onTap(),`
```

This is the function in the provider class

```
'void onTap(){
currentIndex = index;
notifyListeners();
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually calling the function and assigning the result to the **onTap** property.

Either you do it like:

```dart
onTap: Provider.of<Infomation>(context).onTap
```

without calling it, which assigns the function reference to it, or just call it inside like:

```dart
onTap: () {
   Provider.of<Infomation>(context).onTap();
}
```

Try also to just keep a single reference of the extracted provider, since in the case that you may need it the provider again, you're gonna have to do that long thing again. Try doing at the top of the build method like:

```dart
var infoProvider = Provider.of<Infomation>(context, listen: false);
```

Then use the methods off of the **infoProvider** instance like **infoProvider.onTap()** and such.